# Python: return dont work

Tags: python, factorial

I write this code and I have a problem with return.

```
def factorial(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    recurse = factorial(n - 1)
    result = n * recurse
    return result
factorial(3)
```

When I run it I have that output:

> Process finished with exit code 0

And thats it all but when i try it with print i have someting extra:

code:

```
def factorial(n):
  if n == 0:
    print ("1")
  else:
    recurse = factorial(n - 1)
    result = n * recurse
    print(result)
factorial(3)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ptr/Desktop/python/Python_w/brbd/rek.py", line 16, in <module>
    factorial(3)
  File "C:/Users/Ptr/Desktop/python/Python_w/brbd/rek.py", line 13, in factorial
    recurse = factorial(n - 1)
  File "C:/Users/Ptr/Desktop/python/Python_w/brbd/rek.py", line 13, in factorial
    recurse = factorial(n - 1)
  File "C:/Users/Ptr/Desktop/python/Python_w/brbd/rek.py", line 14, in factorial
    result = n * recurse
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My question is - why when I try run that with return I don't see anything and what about second code with print?

Maybe my question or issues is stupid, but humans learn from their mistakes

Comment: Your first function is correct. But you return a value and print nothing. Instead, print out the result: `print(factorial(3))`

Comment: When i run with this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ptr/Desktop/python/Python_w/79str_brudnopis/brbd.py", line 16, in <module>
    factorial(5)
  File "C:/Users/Ptr/Desktop/python/Python_w/79str_brudnopis/brbd.py", line 13, in factorial
    recurse = factorial(n - 1)
  File "C:/Users/Ptr/Desktop/python/Python_w/79str_brudnopis/brbd.py", line 13, in factorial
    recurse = factorial(n - 1)

andddd 10.000... same errors

Comment: Just _copy_ the code at the top of your question and run it like I said, because **it works**.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48246330/4909087

Comment: Yes. Thanks :D im blind. Thank you for your time! And see what @Barmar write and you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second version you don't return anything when `n == 0`, you just print `1`. As a result, the function returns `None`, which you can't multiply.

The first version is correct, but if you want to see the result you have to write:

```
print(factorial(3))
```

---

For reference, this is your code in its entirety.

```
def factorial(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    recurse = factorial(n - 1)
    result = n * recurse
    return result

print(factorial(3))
```

Comment: Apologies, took the liberty to edit your answer because [OP doesn't seem to get it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48246307/python-return-dont-work?noredirect=1#comment83475366_48246307).

Comment: Okay. Thanks - im blind. Thank you for your time